# How do I change the keystore location in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin, keystore

I pulled a project from a friend who uses a Mac. When I try build in Windows (i changed the path first), it read the last path. How can I fix it?

Comment: Clear your `obj/bin` folders from your project and read through a [Diagnostic Build Output](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/troubleshooting/#Diagnostic_MSBuild_Output) to see where the default paths are.

Comment: i have clean it, but it is still same like before... it reads my friend's path (although i have changed it)...

Answer (score 0):

Same issue I had:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\\bin\java.exe -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\27.0.1\lib\apksigner.jar" sign --ks "/Users/techmentdev/Documents/Xamarin Development/keystore/ECG Check/ecgcheck.keystore" --ks-pass pass:ecgcheck --ks-key-alias ecgcheck --key-pass pass:ecgcheck --min-sdk-version 21 --max-sdk-version 28  E:\Project\Cardiac\mobile\gen2\Mobile\Mobile.Droid\bin\Debug\com.cardiacdesigns.generic-Signed.apk 
1>Failed to load signer "signer #1"
1>java.io.FileNotFoundException: \Users\techmentdev\Documents\Xamarin Development\keystore\ECG Check\ecgcheck.keystore (The system cannot find the path specified)
1>at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
1>at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
1>at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
1>at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
1>at com.android.apksigner.ApkSignerTool$SignerParams.loadKeyStoreFromFile(ApkSignerTool.java:828)
1>at com.android.apksigner.ApkSignerTool$SignerParams.loadPrivateKeyAndCertsFromKeyStore(ApkSignerTool.java:719)
1>at com.android.apksigner.ApkSignerTool$SignerParams.loadPrivateKeyAndCerts(ApkSignerTool.java:659)
1>at com.android.apksigner.ApkSignerTool$SignerParams.access$500(ApkSignerTool.java:611)
1>at com.android.apksigner.ApkSignerTool.sign(ApkSignerTool.java:266)
1>at com.android.apksigner.ApkSignerTool.main(ApkSignerTool.java:89)
1>MSB6006: "java.exe" exited with code 2.
1>Done executing task "AndroidApkSigner" -- FAILED.
1>Done building target "_Sign" in project "Mobile.Droid.csproj" -- FAILED.
1>Done building project "Mobile.Droid.csproj" -- FAILED.
1>Build FAILED.
1>Deployment failed to Motorola Moto C.
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

To resolved :

[cmd to signed apk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkdJK.png)

highlighted location is my system existing keystore path

then execute it.

now signed apk ready to use

[signed apk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMZLc.png)

Comment: The commands in your post and the [linked image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkdJK.png) are exactly the same, but give different results... ?